# Can this selector be shortened?

Tags: css, less

I've been using Less CSS for a little while - primarily for the basics.

I have this scenario - I've tried to shorten it but not found a solution as yet, but it feels like it should be possible. Any ideas?

```
.grid-container
{
    & > h1, & > h2, & > h3, & > h4, & > h5, & > h6
    {
        &:extend(.grid);
    }
}
```

I want to apply the extend to all children of `.grid-container`, that are headers. I know that I can remove the ampersand, but is there a short code route? I'm thinking something like this (which doesn't work):

```
& > h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector is already short and I don't think you really need to shorten it further. But if you really wish to do so for whatever reasons, you could try the below:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  .grid-container > &:extend(.grid){};
}
```

Here, the `&` means every selector in the parent selector group and so you will get the properties of `.grid` extended to all headings under `.grid-container`.

**Compiled CSS**

```
.grid,
.grid-continer > h1,
.grid-continer > h2,
.grid-continer > h3,
.grid-continer > h4,
.grid-continer > h5,
.grid-continer > h6 {
  /* rules */
}
```

---

Or, even more simpler would be to assign one common class to all the headings and then just do the following:

```
.grid-container .common-props-for-all-headings:extend(.grid){};
```

```css
.grid-container .common-props-for-all-headings{
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
h1{
  color: red;
}
h2{
  color: blue;
}
h3{
  color: green;
}
h4{
  color: orange;
}
h5{
  color: gold;
}
h6{
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid-container'>
  <h1 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 1</h1>
  <h2 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 2</h2>
  <h3 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 3</h3>
  <h4 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 4</h4>
  <h5 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 5</h5>
  <h6 class='common-props-for-all-headings'>Heading 6</h6>
</div>
```